# WordPress pluggin not working with multiple instances of shortcode on the page (Social Discount Press)

Tags: wordpress

The problem can be seen this page: http://ignitingthesixthsense.com/pre-launch-1

The issue is with the pluggin called Social Discount Press.  The purpose of this pluggin is that it prompts the user to share your webpage via social media, and if they do so a link will then appear giving them access to restricted content.

There are actually 2 problems, but I am not sure if they stem from the same issue or not.

1) The first issue is that I have placed the social share buttons on the page twice using this shortcode:

```
[social_sharing_discount index="2"]
```

And the second instance of the share buttons (towards the bottom of the page) do not work properly.  The Facebook and Twitter button activate the share box when clicked, but after sharing, the "instant access" button does not appear beneath the share button as it should.  And the Google button does nothing at all when clicked.  I have found that if I remove the 1st instance of the share buttons (at the top of the page), then the second instance of them starts working, so in other words it only seems to work properly if there is one instance on the page at a time.

2) The second and much much smaller issue, is that when the Google share button is clicked, the access button appears before the person actually shares.

And assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the main cause of the issue was due to the pluggin being built mainly on ID's which need to be unique across the page.  And having multiple instances of the same ID was causing many errors.

The solution was to rewrite some of the php and js to use Classes instead of ID's.  This allowed for two instances of the pluggin to work on the same page, thus solving problem number one.

The reason why the google one is so inaccurate is because the author simply opens up a popup to the google share page in a popup, this doesn't allow us to see the JS events such as when we share.

On the other hand because the twitter and facebook jssdk are loaded into the page, we know the exact moment when there has been either of those have been shared and thus accurately display the instant access button.

Due to this the author of the pluggin is just doing a best guess as to when the user is likely to have shared. It this case the author is guessing that when the javascript onunload event fires, that logically the user has shared on google. Now the onunload event can be fired in multiple ways, one is when the user closes the popup, i.e the best guess scenario as to if the user has shared. However the onunload event also fires when the form loses focus, a user naviagtes a way or a link is clicked.

Furthermore the onunload event is only properly supported in IE, FF and Safari, not Chrome and Opera. Which in the end gives it differeing behaviour in different browsers.

All of this can lead to unpredicatable behaviour, such as what you are noticing.

A better solution would be for google to have a jssdk for the the google plus share that let's us create a share box on the fly, however it's lacking that functionality as of now.